# I can't change the colour of subtitle in actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to change the color of subtitle in actionbar but it doesn't change.

Here is the screenshot.
[image]

Here is styles.xml

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
    Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
    res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
    backward-compatibility can go here.       
    -->

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@color/actionbarBackground</item>
    <item name="android:tabStripEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `android:subtitleTextStyle` attribute is inherit of `Widget.ActionBar`. You need to move it into your `MyActionBar` style, not your root theme.

Also, don't forget to add support library compatibility since you're using AppCompat:

```
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    ...
    <item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="subtitleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there a documentation about styling in Android.
Documentation on developer.android.com doesn't even mention subtitle styling.

Comment: @salihrkc Don't forget you can always check [Android's styles](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml#L1162) if you're ever unsure. 

They also list [all of the attrs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html) on the  Android Developers website.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your activity file

```
 actionBar.setSubtitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='subtitleColor'>Here ActionBar Subtitle</font>"));
```